# Detect if Facebook app is running from a fanpage (server side)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Is it possible to detect if a Facebook app is running from inside a fan page ?

I've tried using the signed_request data, but it's not being updated when the user moves from the fan page to the full app (and vice versa). Refreshing the page solves the problem (but isn't a proper solution).

I've seen other apps doing this, but I can't figure out how.

Thanks

Update:
Ended up adding a GET variable to the url (Facebook allows you to use different urls for the fan page/canvas apps) and passing that variable throughout the site (couldn't use a cookie as it gave false positives when users moved between the different views of the app)

Comment: `signed_request` data is only sent on the first page load (or when you refresh). What do you mean by "full app"? Are users clicking a link to open your website, or going to a canvas page still inside of facebook?

Comment: It is still not clear if by "full-app" you are referencing to a canvas application or an external website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cant find a serverside solution, then try this:

This bit of javascript might help determine if it's embeded in an iFrame, which is the case for a page tab app.

`var isEmbeded = !(top === self);` then AJAX that up to your server.

Comment: Thanks. 

Your solution works great, but I'd rather user a server side solution. Will update my question if I find an answer.